# How can I remove line break tags from a character vector with Regular Expressions

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How can I remove the `\n` line break tag from a string using regular expressions?

I tried using stringr::str_replace(), but failed.

For example, I have the string:

```
  text= "de sentir sua atitude\n\n  ela merece\n\n  ele não dos cabelos\n\n  você vai te puxo pra caralho só no corpo nele e berrar que não sei dizer alguma coisa\nem precisar ser tão bonita o meio das outras\n\n  no chão.\nespecialmente quando ele levou tanto buscava. minha mãe dele guardada na banheira\n\n  \n\n  e eu te amar\n\n   me desapaixonar por causa da festa\n\n  você ama e\nde fato\nte amar é como um.\nque possamos nada especial acho que você imagina a conexão ou onde a independência aqui bocas nunca teve o amor com esta é seu ambiente\nnão"
```

And I tried using `[:punct:]n`, and `\\n{1,}`, but all of them failed in doing so when I ran than into the replacement function with:

`stringr::str_replace(text, '([:punct:]n|\\n{1,})', ' ')`

Comment: what is `n` in the code.  Also, `str_replace` may need a `replacement`

Comment: Do you need `stringr::str_remove_all(text, '([[:punct:]]|\\n{1,})')`

Comment: oh, I forgot to write it here in SO, but I used the replacement argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_remove_all` which would make it compact instead of using the replacement argument in `str_replace_all` with `""`

```
stringr::str_remove_all(text, '([[:punct:]]|\\n{1,})')
```

NOTE: `str_replace` replaces only the first instance and not more than one

Answer (score 1):

Using R base

```
string <- "aaaa\naaaaaaa\naaaaa\n"
gsub('\n', '', string)
```

will output
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

Also works with your text. Sometimes the simplest is the best solution, no  need for regex, it is technically a literal match.

Comment: Also, since it is a literal match, fixed=T would make it way faster if you are working with a big text.

Comment: that is correct, but `gsub` default uses `fixed = FALSE`